# Why is bootstrap loaded in Django project and my CSS file isn't?

Tags: python, html, css, django, static

I'm new in **Python/Django** and I'm trying to create a little project. I'm running **Python 3.8.2** and **Django 3.0.6** on **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**.

I'm still developing so I'm testing and running the webpages with **"python manage.py runserver" (debug=True)**. I'm having a really hard time trying to load my own **CSS** style.

The project is organized like this:

```
PROJECT FOLDER
|   --virtualenv
|   --media
|   --myproject
|   --myapp
    |   --migrations
    |   --templates
        |   --myapp
    |   --static
        |   --favicon
        |   --style
        |   --vendor
            |   --bootstrap
            |   --jquery
|   --templates
    |   --parcials
```

I have this configuration in my **"settings.py"** (which is inside **"myproject"** folder) related to the **static files**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, '/myapp/static'), )
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

In the **head** of the **html** which is rendered, I have:

```
{% load static %}
...
<link href="{% static 'favicon/favicon.ico' %}" rel="shortcut icon">
<link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/theme_1564087106285.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link hrel="{% static 'style/index.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The **"index.css"** is inside the **style folder** and it has just a **class selector**:

```
.style-v1 {
  font-size: x-large;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

In the **html body**, I just try to test the **css** loading with:

```
<div class="style-v1">
    CSS loading test
</div>
```

I don't know if I'm forgetting something or if there's something wrong, I'm still fresh in **PYTHON/DJANGO/HTML/CSS**, but the **bootstrap** works fine, as well as the **favicon**, and the **"index.css"** isn't loaded, which I checked at **Network** tab of **Chrome dev tools**.

I apolagize for any typo or if my description is not enough for understanding the problem utterly, I'm also new posting question in this community. I'm completely grateful if someone would give me a light to solve this problem.

**My best regards!**

EDIT:
@Anoop K George, figure out the problem, it was a typo in the link attribute "href", apparently I didn't notice I typed "hrel".

Comment: have you figured it out now ?

Comment: No, I did like you said and created the "appname" folder inside "static" and move the static files there, but after that the bootstrap stopped to be loaded and my css still not being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Django conventions, create your a folder in your app name in static folder and move all your static files into it.

PROJECT FOLDER

```
|   --virtualenv
|   --media
|   --myproject
|   --myapp
    |   --migrations
    |   --templates
        |   --myapp
    |   --static
        |   --myapp
          |   --favicon
          |   --style
          |   --vendor
            |   --bootstrap
            |   --jquery
|   --templates
    |   --parcials
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything in the "settings.py"?

Comment: in your static loading tag change hrel to href, <link hrel="{% static 'style/index.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> to <link href="{% static 'style/index.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: try adding bootstrap with cdn;https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: That's it! It was a typo in the link attribute "href", I typed "hrel". Thank you very much, @Anoop K George. I can't believe I didn't see this. I'm so grateful!

Comment: You are welcome, if you like my answer accept and vote